# Replacing a string with strings that include parenthesis issue

Tags: c#, regex, replace, checkedlistbox

i am currenty having a problem related with regex.replace . I have an item in checkedlistbox that contains a string with parenthesis "()" :

```
regx2[4] = new Regex( "->" + checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

the example setence inside the selected item is

```
hello how are you (today)
```

i use it in regex like this :

```
if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked)
{
    //replaces the string without parenthesis with the one with parenthesis
    //ex:<reason1> ----> hello, how are you (today) (worked fine)
    richTextBox1.Text = regx2[selected].Replace(richTextBox1.Text,"->"+checkedListBox1.Items[selected].ToString());
}
else if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Unchecked)
{
    //replaces the string with parenthesis with the one without parenthesis
    //hello, how are you (today)----><reason1> (problem)
    richTextBox1.Text = regx2[4].Replace(richTextBox1.Text, "<reason" + (selected + 1).ToString() + ">");
}
```

it is able to replace the string on the first condition but unable to re-replace the setences again on second because it has parenthesis "()", do you know how to solve this problem?? 
thx for the response :)

Comment: string.Replace should be fine for what you want to do

Comment: Shorten the code to include only relevant parts. No need to mess with GUI, for example

Comment: btw could you give some examples for the problem above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
regx2[4] = new Regex( "->" + checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Try:

```
regx2[4] = new Regex(Regex.Escape("->" + checkedListBox1.SelectedItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

To use any of the special characters as a literal in a regex, you need to escape them with a backslash. If you want to match `1+1=2`, the correct regex is `1\+1=2`. Otherwise, the plus sign has a special meaning.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html

**special characters:**

- backslash \,
- caret ^,
- dollar sign $,
- period or dot .,
- vertical bar or pipe symbol |,
- question mark ?,
- asterisk or star *,
- plus sign +,
- opening parenthesis (,
- closing parenthesis ),
- opening square bracket [,
- opening curly brace {

To ***fix*** it you could probably do this:

```
regx2[4] = new Regex("->" + checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("(", @"\(").Replace(")", @"\)"));
```

But I would just use `string.replace()` since you aren't doing any parsing. I can't tell what you're transforming from/to and why you use `selected` as an index on the regex array in the `if` and 4 as the index in the `else`.

Comment: could you give some example for that?? i have tried that, but it is still failed to change the setence..